# Using Filter on an Dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, filtering

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the filter() functionality in swift.

I have a dictionary defined as such (where I keep a count of the colors found in a photo) :

```
var colorCounts = Dictionary<UIColor, Int>()
```

I would like to remove the key/value pairs from the dictionary that have a count of less than 50, but I can't seem to get the right syntax for the filter() down.

Can anyone explain how you would use it in this case?

Answer (score 4):

```
colorCounts.forEach { if $1 < 50 { colorCounts[$0] = nil } }
```

A one line solution.

Comment: Neat for mutation solution! I think you should add this answer (possibly with a small explanation to short key-value pair removal syntax) to the linked duplicate thread (as that thread will not be marked as a duplicate); the existing solution in that thread do show how to remove objects from dictionary, but not using this compact `dict[key]=nil` solution. (Possibly mention the `=nil` syntax with reference [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html))

Comment: Thanks, I'm taking a look and if I my answer can improve that question in any way, I'll add it as a comment / answer :)

Comment: I think it'll be a good complement to the existing answer.

Answer (score 3):

When you filter a dictionary, each key-value pair become a tuple of `(key, value)`. Try this:

```
let result = colorCounts.filter {
    $0.1 >= 50
}.reduce([UIColor: Int]()) { (var aggregate, elem) in
    aggregate[elem.0] = elem.1
    return aggregate
}
```

`filter` will return an array of tuples. `reduce` take this array to build a new dictionary.

Comment: A while ago (maybe a year) I've noticed some noticeable performance decrease when using multiple high lvl functions, especially when using reduce to create another array. Any chance you have any experience with it?

Comment: I haven't bench tested it to be honest. Typically I don't care about performance until it becomes a problem. As Donald Knuth said: "premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: Some thoughts (and measurements) about using reduce() to build an array (or dictionary) can be found here: http://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/08/03/arrays-linked-lists-and-performance/. It is slow because – as I understand it – a new array/dictionary is created in each iteration step.

Answer (score 1):

You could define an extension to `Dictionary` that filters out elements from `self`, and call it accordingly:

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func filterSelf(@noescape includeElement: (Dictionary.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> () {
        for (k, v) in self {
            if try !includeElement((k, v)) { self.removeValueForKey(k) }
        }
    }
}

var colorCounts = Dictionary<UIColor, Int>()
colorCounts.filterSelf { $0.1 >= 50 }
```

The alternative is to use the native `Dictionary.filter(..)` method, but this will return an array to you.

```
var colorCounts = Dictionary<UIColor, Int>()
print(colorCounts.dynamicType) // Dictionary<UIColor, Int>
let filteredCounts = colorCounts.filter { $0.1 >= 50 }
print(filteredCounts.dynamicType) // Array<(UIColor, Int)>
```

Which could naturally be re-transformed into a dictionary, but if you're ok with mutating the original dictionary object, the extension method above should use the smallest overhead.